# Android Face Detection using OpenCV/JavaCV

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I want to know how I implement Android Face Detection using OpenCV/JavaCV. Any one have idea about that or have code please comment on this or put the code. I want get faces from the Phone Gallery and detect them..

Answer (score 6):

For face detectiion you can use the built in [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) in the Android SDK, It returns face positions and angles in BMPs. But it's not very fast.

You can Also use the javaCV face detection but before to start i recommend you to see this [article](http://www.smallscreendesign.com/2011/01/25/about-face-detection-on-android-part-1/) to see advantages and constarint of some API that you can use and also compare Performance

[image: some]

**For FaceDetector you can see these links**

1. [Link 1](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html)
2. [Link 2](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/android-face-detection-example/)

Here's a [realtime face detection](http://jjil.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FaceDetect-Android/) sample using FaceDetector and OpenGL (draws rectangles) which works in Android 2.2

**You can also use [OpenCV in Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android)**

You'd better try this on Linux (I've tried it on Windows, but failed).

**Finally [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)** (strongly recommended)

There is a sample code of realtime face detection using the camera. See "javacv-src-*.zip" on the download page.

Answer (score 0):

The timing figures on the screenshot from K_Anas are shockingly slow... my app on my HTC Desire S with the OpenCV library ([here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android)) does 4+ fps...

My demo app on Play Store (eurgh) is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=barry.opencvdemo). In the menu the first item takes you to [my web page for the app](http://www.barrythomas.co.uk/code.html) with source code snippets. 1) install OpenCV, 2) get the supplied samples running, 3) edit "Tutorial 2 OpenCVSamples" and drop my code snippets into the frame processing loop.

I claim no credit for the app, it is just a slightly enlarged and adjusted version of the sample which comes with the OpenCV library.